# Store or checkpoint a partially trained scikit-learn model to disk

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm running a Gradient Boosting model that takes around 11 hours to train. I'm using a pre-emptible instance on Google Cloud to do this (because it's way cheaper). The problem is, I keep losing my progress because the instance gets terminated before the model is able to finish training.

Is there a way to checkpoint or save the progress of a partially trained model to disk? such that the training should resume from where it left off when I rerun the code.

I know there's the *pickle* module which allows me to dump objects on disk. But I'm not looking to save a fully trained model, but a partially trained one.

Answer (score 1):

Check [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/49012/checkpoints-in-sklearn) with similar question.

For Gradient Boosting with sklearn, you can set with warm_start.